# TDengine's golang example code does not work

Tags: go, tdengine

I get errors when running the TDengine's golang example code.

go code:

```
// drop database if exists
sqlStr := "drop database if exists " + dbName
_, err = db.Exec(sqlStr)
checkErr(err, sqlStr)

I forgot to record the error, I only remember it shows database does not exist, same as the error2 below

And I can run these commands successfully by using the console.
error2

go code:

sqlStr := "insert into " + dbName + "." + childTblPrefix + strconv.Itoa(tID) + " values "
```

docker error:

```
01/19 18:33:11.390574 00000029 MND ERROR msg:0x7f69d0003b40, app:0xaa table:0.log.vgroup_3, failed to get table meta, table not exist
01/19 18:33:11.391065 00000067 TSC ERROR 0xa9 get multi-tableMeta failed, code:Table does not exist
01/19 18:33:11.391518 00000038 TSC ERROR 0xa9 async result callback, code:Table does not exist
01/19 18:33:11.391917 00000036 MON ERROR table vgroup_3 not exist, create table vgroup_3
```

```
OS: wsl2 in win10
Memory, CPU, current Disk Space
TDengine Version: I test with 2.4.0.0 & 2.4.0.4 by using docker
Golang driver with Linux client 2.4.0.0
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in the log, there error is Table does not exist.
You have to confirm that if the table name is right? Or the table is deleted by other opertaion.